# regex which will identify text containing a | but only if it is not within ' anywhere else in the text

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to devise a Perl regex as an `if` condition that identifies | but will fail if the | is contained anywhere in a quoted string such as 'It went >| CRASH |< as it fell on the floor'

Example inputs are below

This should match:

```
action 71|55|279|286|155|57|343
```

This should fail to match:

```
action mud_destroyset($me,$arg,$arg1,$arg2,'gun','2','There is an almighty >| CRASH |< . When the smoke clears, both door and sphere are gone...','You hear the >| CRASH |< of a cannon going off in the distance.','',0,$cid,$oc) ;
```

I have tried negative lookbehind regex as follows and fiddled extensively and failed. I even asked ChatGPT and it failed.

These didn't work (the 1st one is ChatGPT solution, the 2nd is my attempt):

```
^(?:(?!'\|).)*\|
(?<!').+\|.+
```

https://regex101.com/r/1o0SOM/1

https://regex101.com/r/z5Xz83/1

Help appreciated!

Comment: What if you have both in the same string? E.g. `foo | '|BAR|'`

Comment: @TLP This won't happen in my data fortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some experimentation I found a solution that worked for me, although it is not perfect as it will not produce a match if there is any string literal before the pipe, but works for all my input data cases.

```
^(?!.*\').*\|
```

https://regex101.com/r/QZKMKS/1

A more sophisticated solution was also suggested on reddit:

```
'[^']+'(*SKIP)(*F)|\|
```

https://regex101.com/r/z5Xz83/2

Answer (score 2):

One way could be removing anything between single quotes and then looking for the pipe:

```perl
index($txt =~ s/'[^']*'//gr, "|") != -1
```

An example run:

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @texts = ("action 71|55|279|286|155|57|343",
             "action 'There is this >| CRASH |< .'");

for my $txt (@texts) {
    print index($txt =~ s/'[^']*'//gr, "|") != -1 ? "yes\n" : "no\n";
}
```

which gives

```
yes
no
```

---

- `'`: literal single quote
- `[^']*`: anything but single quote, repetad as many times as possible
- `'`: again a literal single quote
- "g" flag: global replacement
- "r" flag: nondestructive, i.e., return a new string

and `index` function looks for the substring ("|") and returns -1 if it cannot find it in the searched string.

Comment: What about strings with escaped quotes? `'That\'s me'`

Comment: @TLP that escalates it quickly :) I think that's somewhat the same issue as unbalanced quotes like 'yes no' why| here'. If the asker shows a concern, i will delete the answer which wouldn't be an answer at that point

Comment: @TLP  In my data either there are strings and it shouldn't match or there are no strings and it should match. So if there is an escaped ' that there must have been a string, regardless of where the | is, and so it shouldn't match.

Comment: Don't really need for regex then: first check if there is a quote: return false if so. otherwise, return whether there is a |. Although, an escaped quote doesn't necessarily imply outer quotes but it's your data.